# Keyboard moves UICollectionView cell off screen

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

so I have created a UICollectionViewController, made each cell the size of the screen and enabled the function to scroll horizontally between the cells like pages.

[image: Gif scrolling example]

My problem is whenever the keyboard comes up (as I plan to populate the cells with some input to get from the user) it pushes the content off the screen.

[image: Keyboard pushing content]

I am not sure how to stop this, and I have looked online but to no avail. The best I could find is [this question also on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256752/uicollectionview-contentoffset-changes-when-keyboard-appears) but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please share relevant code

Comment: Yes, you should share your code. It looks like you're doing  _something_ to your collection view's contentOffset or contentInset otherwise it wouldn't respond all all usually.